Fine-Tuning LLMs: CUDA OOM Errors Despite Various Optimization Techniques
I'm working on fine-tuning an LLM to build a fantasy football league model. The goal is to have the model output a team with high potential (hopefully) given a round of games. I have built an RAG dataset and implemented custom loss functions and metrics to fine-tune the model.
Problem: Regardless of the model I try to fine-tune, I consistently encounter a CUDA Out Of Memory (OOM) error. I've attempted to fine-tune various models, starting with Mistral-7B and going down to models with as few as 410M parameters (EleutherAI/pythia-410m, bigscience/bloomz-560m*)*. However, the OOM issue persists even with smaller models.
Environment Details:

EC2 Instance: g5.2xlarge

GPU: A100 with 24 GB VRAM

CPU RAM: 32 GB


What I Tried:

Lowered batch size to 1

Add gradient accumulation

Mixed precision training

QLoRA (even pythia-410m loaded in 4-bit with fine-tuned with LoRA PEFT method crashed with OOM error)

Gradient checkpointing

Cancel out the RAG pipeline

torch.cuda.empty_cache()


Despite these efforts, the OOM error still occurs. Given the hardware, I expected it to handle at least the smaller models without running into memory issues.
Notes:

I set max_length=4096 as my input sequences are very long (could be 1000-4000 tokens).

I'm using HuggingFace transformers library


I'm attaching my DataCollator and the training function:
class FantasyTeamDataCollator:
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, rag_retriever: SeasonSpecificRAG, max_length: int, eval_steps: int):

        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.rag_retriever = rag_retriever
        self.max_length = max_length
        self.eval_steps = eval_steps
        self.steps = 0
    def __call__(self, batch):

        teams_batch = [sample['teams'] for sample in batch]
        dates_batch = [sample['date'] for sample in batch]
        seasons_batch = [sample['season'] for sample in batch]

        rag_info_batch = self.rag_retriever.retrieve_relevant_info(teams_batch, dates_batch, seasons_batch)

        processed_samples = []
        for i, sample in enumerate(batch):
            processed_samples.append(self.process_sample(sample, rag_info_batch[i]))
        processed_samples = [result for result in processed_samples if result is not None]               

        if not processed_samples:
            raise ValueError("All samples in the batch failed to process")

        batch_output = self.collate_batch(processed_samples)
        return batch_output

    def process_sample(self, sample: Dict[str, Any], rag_info: Dict[str, List[str]]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        combined_input = self.combine_input_with_rag(sample['text'], rag_info)
        input_encodings = self.tokenizer(combined_input, truncation=True,
                                         max_length=self.max_length, padding="max_length")

        return {
            "input_ids": torch.tensor(input_encodings["input_ids"]),
            "attention_mask": torch.tensor(input_encodings["attention_mask"]),
            "labels": torch.tensor(input_encodings["input_ids"]),
            "matches": sample['matches'],
            "round": sample['round']
        }

    def combine_input_with_rag(self, input_text: str, rag_info: Dict[str, List[str]]) -> str:

        combined_input = (f"{input_text}\n\n"
                          f"Relevant Information:\n"
                          f"Teams Info:{rag_info['teams']}\n"
                          f"Players Info:{rag_info['players']}")

        # add system prompts occasionally
        if self.steps % self.eval_steps == 0:
            combined_input = (f"Instructions: {instruction_prompt}\n\n"
                              f"League Rules: {full_rules_prompt}\n\n"
                              f"{combined_input}")
        self.steps += 1
        return combined_input

    u/staticmethod
    def collate_batch(batch):
        return {
            "input_ids": torch.stack([item["input_ids"] for item in batch]),
            "attention_mask": torch.stack([item["attention_mask"] for item in batch]),
            "labels": torch.stack([item["labels"] for item in batch]),
            "matches": [item["matches"] for item in batch],
            "round": [item["round"] for item in batch]
        }

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def fine_tune(self):

    train_dataset = self.fantasy_dataset.dataset_dict['train']
    eval_dataset = self.fantasy_dataset.dataset_dict['test']

    early_stopping_callback = EarlyStoppingCallback(
        early_stopping_patience=5,
        early_stopping_threshold=0.01,
    )

    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=self.out_dir,
        num_train_epochs=self.num_epochs,
        per_device_train_batch_size=self.bz,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=self.bz,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=self.conf.train.accumulation_steps,
        load_best_model_at_end=True,
        metric_for_best_model='combined_score',
        greater_is_better=True,
        eval_strategy='epoch',
        eval_steps=self.eval_steps,
        save_strategy='epoch',
        save_total_limit=10,
        fp16=False,
        bf16=True,
        remove_unused_columns=False,
        max_grad_norm=1.0,
        gradient_checkpointing=True
    )

    print('\nBegin fine-tuning the model')
    trainer = FantasyTrainer(
        model=self.model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
        data_collator=self.data_collator,
        compute_metrics=self.compute_metrics,
        callbacks=[early_stopping_callback],
        fantasy_team_loss=self.fantasy_team_loss,
        eval_steps=self.eval_steps,
        initial_structure_weight=self.structure_weight,
        min_structure_weight=self.min_structure_weight
    )
    trainer.train()

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class FantasyTrainer(Trainer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Extract custom arguments
        self.fantasy_team_loss = kwargs.pop('fantasy_team_loss', None)
        self.eval_steps = kwargs.pop('eval_steps', 100)
        self.structure_weight = kwargs.pop('initial_structure_weight', 1.0)
        self.min_structure_weight = kwargs.pop('min_structure_weight', 0.1)

        # Initialize Trainer with remaining arguments
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.steps = 0
        self.losses = {
            'loss': [],
            'lm_loss': [],
            'structure_loss': []
        }

    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):

        model_inputs = {k: v for k, v in inputs.items() if k in ['input_ids', 'attention_mask']}
        outputs = model(**model_inputs)

        # Calculate custom loss
        lm_loss, structure_loss = self.fantasy_team_loss(outputs.logits, inputs['input_ids'])

        # Combine losses with updated weight
        total_loss = lm_loss + (self.structure_weight * structure_loss)

        # Add L2 regularization
        l2_lambda = 0.01  # Adjust this value as needed
        l2_reg = torch.sum(torch.stack([p.pow(2.0).sum() for p in model.parameters()]))
        total_loss += l2_lambda * l2_reg

        # Update losses
        self.losses['loss'].append(total_loss.item())
        self.losses['lm_loss'].append(lm_loss.item())
        self.losses['structure_loss'].append(structure_loss.item())

        # Log metrics every eval_steps
        if self.steps % self.eval_steps == 0:
            self._log_metrics()

        # Decrease structure weight over time
        self.structure_weight = np.maximum(self.min_structure_weight, self.structure_weight * 0.9)

        self.steps += 1
        return (total_loss, outputs) if return_outputs else total_loss

    def _move_model_to_device(self, model, device):
        pass

    def train(self, resume_from_checkpoint: Union[str, bool] = None,
              trial: Union["optuna.Trial", Dict[str, Any]] = None, **kwargs):
        # Reset steps and losses before training
        self.steps = 0
        self.losses = {k: [] for k in self.losses}
        return super().train(resume_from_checkpoint, trial, **kwargs)

Questions:

Is the hardware I'm using insufficient for fine-tuning, particularly for models with sequence lengths up to 4096 tokens?

Are there additional optimizations or techniques I should consider to mitigate the OOM errors?


Any insights, suggestions, or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
